# Has CodeIgniter 2.0 / PHPUnit happened yet?

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, codeigniter-2

So i've just had a pretty disappointing morning/weekend. It came in the form of setting up PHPUnit, Integrating Eclipse etc

Now i've just discovered that there's no straightforward way to test CodeIgniter 2.0 applications directly from PHPUnit.

I've spent a lot of time researching libraries (FooStack and CIUnit) but the development of these has ceased and aren't compatible with CI 2.0

Before I jump in the inlcuded 2.0 Unit Testing class I need to ask, have I missed out on any major developments around CI 2.0 and PHPUnit.

Any guidance greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Conor

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A quick note to anybody interested in this. Ellis Labs are currently baking support for PHPUnit in CodeIgniter Reactor. The next release should have it.. Ref: [ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/187601](https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/187601)

Answer (score 2):

I found a few resources you may find useful.

A class written to integrate PHPunit and Codeigniter. Not a very interesting forum post, but it lead me to the next link. 
http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/70934/P60

However, the repository found in the link above doesn't look very active. This fork of it seems to be a little more active:
https://bitbucket.org/kenjis/my-ciunit

Comment: I read the forum post you are referring to, wasn't really impressed but that fork looks interesting.. I'll look into that alright. Thanks :D